# SDL2.0 Alternative for SDL_Overlay

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sdl, sdl-2

So I've been trying to go through the following tutorial on ffmpeg: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial02.html

However, when I try to compile using gcc, I get the following output:

```
root:/Users/mbrodeur/Downloads/HACKATHON CONTENT/Tutorials-> gcc -o tutorial02 tutorial02.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm -lswscale -D_THREAD_SAFE -lSDL2
tutorial02.c: In function ‘main’:
tutorial02.c:41: error: ‘SDL_Overlay’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tutorial02.c:41: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
tutorial02.c:41: error: for each function it appears in.)
tutorial02.c:41: error: ‘bmp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tutorial02.c:98: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
tutorial02.c:110: error: ‘SDL_YV12_OVERLAY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Now, I read that SDL_Overlay is no longer used in SDL2, so therein lies the problem. I've been poking around, but can't seem to find anything helpful. Is there a replacement for SDL_Overlay? Is it necessary?

SDL_Overlay is used in the following context:

```
SDL_Overlay     *bmp;
bmp = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                       SDL_YV12_OVERLAY, screen);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to see the [updated source code](https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial) version of the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that page existed. Unfortunately, the updated source still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you got arround updating the tutorial and get the code to work with sdl2? If so can you share? Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`SDL_CreateTexture()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_CreateTexture) with a YUV pixel format that matches the layout and planar-ity of your decoded frames.

Or use `libswscale` to convert `ffmpeg`'s YUV buffers to RGB.

**EDIT**: SDL2 >= 2.0.1 has [`SDL_UpdateYUVTexture()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateYUVTexture) for updating planar YUV textures so you don't have to manually coalesce `libav`'s buffers any more.

Comment: "This is a fairly slow function, intended for use with static textures." Does not seem very suited for video?

Comment: In SDL_UpdateTexture (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture), which is linked to from your link above (which I assume means it is derived from SDL_UpdateTexture). I am new to OpenGL but thought writing to textures was one of the fastest ways, so I am as surprised as you.. Perhaps SDL's implementation is slow in itself? No matter what, this does not seem like the correct answer for the question as I assume OP wants to display video.

Answer (score 32):

I have updated the tutorial to work with SDL 2.0.1. It replaces SDL_Overlay with SDL_Texture in YV12 format.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    int videoStream;
    unsigned i;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtxOrig = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVCodec *pCodec = NULL;
    AVFrame *pFrame = NULL;
    AVPacket packet;
    int frameFinished;
    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Window *screen;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
    Uint8 *yPlane, *uPlane, *vPlane;
    size_t yPlaneSz, uvPlaneSz;
    int uvPitch;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: test <file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open video file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't open file

    // Retrieve stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStream = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStream = i;
            break;
        }
    if (videoStream == -1)
        return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    pCodecCtxOrig = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
    if (pCodec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }

    // Copy context
    pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    if (avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");
        return -1; // Error copying codec context
    }

    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Could not open codec

    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    // Make a screen to put our video
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "FFmpeg Tutorial",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            pCodecCtx->width,
            pCodecCtx->height,
            0
        );

    if (!screen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create window - exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);
    if (!renderer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create renderer - exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Allocate a place to put our YUV image on that screen
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(
            renderer,
            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12,
            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
            pCodecCtx->width,
            pCodecCtx->height
        );
    if (!texture) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create texture - exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // initialize SWS context for software scaling
    sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
            pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
            AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            SWS_BILINEAR,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

    // set up YV12 pixel array (12 bits per pixel)
    yPlaneSz = pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height;
    uvPlaneSz = pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4;
    yPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(yPlaneSz);
    uPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(uvPlaneSz);
    vPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(uvPlaneSz);
    if (!yPlane || !uPlane || !vPlane) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate pixel buffers - exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    uvPitch = pCodecCtx->width / 2;
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if (frameFinished) {
                AVPicture pict;
                pict.data[0] = yPlane;
                pict.data[1] = uPlane;
                pict.data[2] = vPlane;
                pict.linesize[0] = pCodecCtx->width;
                pict.linesize[1] = uvPitch;
                pict.linesize[2] = uvPitch;

                // Convert the image into YUV format that SDL uses
                sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *) pFrame->data,
                        pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pict.data,
                        pict.linesize);

                SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(
                        texture,
                        NULL,
                        yPlane,
                        pCodecCtx->width,
                        uPlane,
                        uvPitch,
                        vPlane,
                        uvPitch
                    );

                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
            SDL_Quit();
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    free(yPlane);
    free(uPlane);
    free(vPlane);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you updated the other tutorials? Mind sharing? I'm using SDL 2.0, since I can't find the necessary includes on 1.2 download file. +1 for the effort.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"
#include "libswscale\swscale.h"
#include "libswresample\swresample.h"
#include "sdl/SDL.h"
}
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2main.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2test.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avdevice.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avfilter.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "swscale.lib")
`

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem too. I used SDL 1.2 since I didn't know how to replace SDL_Overlay in SDL2.0. If you are on Mac 10.10, you can use this patch
http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/compiling_sheepshaver_basilisk#tidbits

`patch < no-CGDirectPaletteRef.patch`
Then in /src/video/x11/SDL_x11sym.h, replace line 168 and 169 to this

`SDL_X11_SYM(int,_XData32,(Display *dpy,register _Xconst long *data,unsigned len),(dpy,data,len),return)
SDL_X11_SYM(void,_XRead32,(Display *dpy,register long *data,long len),(dpy,data,len), return)`

It worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial links against SDL1 http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php and they should have mentioned it(or they did and I haven't seen it).All works perfectly with SDL1.