# How to rotate SDL_Overlay?

Tags: sdl

I use `SDL` and I want to display image with USB camera.
I'll use `YUV` formatted image and use `SDL_Overlay`.
And I want to rotate the image.

Can I rotate a `SDL_Overlay` object?
I must convert `YUV` image to `BMP`?
The rotation angle are 90 degrees.

Comment: If you are using SDL2, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579286/sdl2-0-alternative-for-sdl-overlay) can help?