# Header file for SDL_Overlay

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I plan to use both `SDL_GetKeyboardState` and `SDL_Overlay` but it seems there is a conflict.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{
    const Uint8 *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    SDL_Overlay *bmp;
    printf("hello world!");
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -c main.cpp
```

---

When order of headers are:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

error: ‘SDL_GetKeyboardState’ was not declared in this scope
 const Uint8 *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
                                                  ^
```

or

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

error: ‘SDL_Overlay’ was not declared in this scope
     SDL_Overlay *bmp;
     ^
```

Even adding

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_video.h>
```

does not solve the problem.

What header should I add to use `SDL_Overlay`?

Comment: You cannot combine both SDL 1.2 and SDL2. You can use [SDL_GetKeyState](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlgetkeystate.html) with SDL 1.2 instead. There are no overlays in SDL2 but look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579286/sdl2-0-alternative-for-sdl-overlay

Comment: @keltar, Many thanks.