# AVFrame and SDL2 for screen capture

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sdl-2, yuv, libav

In that [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391289/header-file-for-sdl-overlay), I realized I cannot use both `SDL` and `SDL2`. Definitely I choose `SDL2` over its precedent.

I had written the following code to capture screen and convert it to an `AVFrame` for video creation:

```
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
...

SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width,height, 0, 0);
SDL_Overlay *bmp = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(width,height, SDL_YV12_OVERLAY, screen);


if(av_frame_make_writable(frame) < 0)
    exit(1);


SDL_LockYUVOverlay(bmp);
memcpy(frame->data[0], bmp->pixels[0], bmp->pitches[0]);
memcpy(frame->data[1], bmp->pixels[1], bmp->pitches[1]);
memcpy(frame->data[2], bmp->pixels[2], bmp->pitches[2]);
SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay(bmp);
```

The problem is that `SDL2` does not support `SDL_Overlay`. The [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579286/) methods are good for playing a video not capturing it. How should I modify this code to replace `SDL_Overlay` and make it suitable for `SDL2`?

Comment: For the person who voted to close this question as too broad, I should mention that all libraries can be used in many ways. But the purpose is one. The question is extremely clear. Do you have one solution at all?

Comment: I may not quite understand it but, are you saying `SDL_Overlay *bmp` in above example doesn't have current frame buffer's planar (yuv) data?

Comment: @thekamilz, No. I mean `SDL_Overlay` is obsolete in SDL2 and I should substitute it with something else. Looking  for a replacement.

Comment: Now I got it. I'm sure you might seen this one but just in case, did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579286/sdl2-0-alternative-for-sdl-overlay

Comment: @thekamilz, what I need is the reverse of  `SDL_UpdateYUVTexture`

Comment: Oh yes, right. OK this is my final try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315980/sdl2-c-taking-a-screenshot . Good luck.